# How to correctly parse a mixed latin/ideographic full text query with regex?

Tags: php, regex, internationalization, full-text-search, cjk

I'm trying to sanitize/format some input using regex for a mixed latin/ideographic(chinese/japanse/korean) full text search.

I found an old example of someone's attempt at sanitizing a latin/asian language string on a forum of which I cannot find again (full credit to the original author of this code).

I am having trouble fully understanding the regex portion of the function in particular why it seems to be treating the numbers 0, 2, and 3 differently than the rest of the latin based numbers 1,4-9 (basically it treats the numbers 0,4-9 properly, but the numbers 0,2-3 in the query are treated as if they are Asian characters).

For example.  I am trying to sanitize the following string:
"hello 1234567890 蓄積した abc123def"

and it will turn into:
"hello 1 456789 abc1 def 2 3 0 蓄 積 し た 2 3"

the correct output for this sanitized string should be:
"hello 1234567890 蓄 積 し た abc123def"

As you can see it properly spaces out the Asian characters but the numbers 0, 2, 3 are treated differently than all other number.  Any help on why the regex is treating those numbers 0,2 and 3 differently would be a great help (or if you know of a better way of achieving a similar result)!  Thank you

I have included the function below

```
function prepareString($str) {
$str = mb_strtolower(trim(preg_replace('#[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\.]+#u', ' ', $str)));

return trim(preg_replace('#\s\s+#u', ' ', preg_replace('#([^\12544-\65519])#u', ' ', $str) . ' ' . implode(' ', preg_split('#([\12544-\65519\s])?#u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY))));
}
```

**UPDATE: Providing context for clarity**

I am authoring a website that will be launched in China.  This website will have a search function and I am trying to write a parser for the search query input.

Unlike the English language which uses a " " as the delimiter between words in a sentence, Chinese does not use spaces between words.  Because of this, I have to re-format a search query by breaking apart each Chinese character and searching for each character individually within the database.  Chinese users will also use latin/english characters for things such as brand names which they can mix together with their Chinese characters (eg. Ivy牛仔舖).

What I would like to do is separate all of the English words out from the Chinese characters, and Seperate each Chinese character with a space.

A search query could look like this: Ivy牛仔舖

And I would want to parse it so that it looks like this: Ivy 牛 仔 舖

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research and the help of Alan's comments I was able to find the correct regex combinations to achieve a query parsing function for seperating lating and ideographic (chinese/japanese) characters that I'm happy with:

```
function prepareString($str) {
    $str = mb_strtolower(trim(preg_replace('#[^\p{L}\p{Nd}]+#u', ' ', $str)));
    return trim(preg_replace('#\s\s+#u', ' ', preg_replace('#\p{Han}#u', ' ', $str) . ' ' . implode(' ', preg_split('#\P{Han}?#u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY))));
}

$query = "米娜Mi-NaNa日系時尚館╭☆ 旅行 渡假風格 【A6402】korea拼接條紋口袋飛鼠棉"

echo prepareString($query); //"mi nana a6402 korea 米 娜 日 系 時 尚 館 旅 行 渡 假 風 格 拼 接 條 紋 口 袋 飛 鼠 棉"
```

Disclaimer: I cannot read mandarin and the string above was copied from a Chinese website.  if it says anything offensive please let me know and I will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be with the regex `[^\12544-\65519]`.  That looks like it's supposed to be a range defined by two, five-digit octal escapes, but it doesn't work that way.  The actual breakdown is like this:

```
\125 => octal escape for 'U'
4    => '4'
4    => '4'
-
\655 => octal escape for... (something)
1    => '1'
9    => '9'
```

Which is effectively the same as:

```
[^14-\655]
```

What `\655` means as the top of a range isn't clear, but the character class matches anything except a '1', a '4', or any ASCII character with a code point higher than '4' (which includes '9' and 'U').  It doesn't really matter though; the important point is that octal escapes can contain a maximum of three digits, which makes them unsuitable for your needs.  I suggest you use PHP's `\x{nnn}` hexadecimal notation instead.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I've been trying to use \x{nnn} as you suggested but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to match an entire range of hexadecimal notation. I can match a single character, but to block out an entire range I cannot seem to find the solution. Any suggestions?  I've also been trying to use the p{Latin} notation but it's giving me trouble because it's giving me similar problems.  eg:"hello 1234567890 蓄積した abc123def" will split to:
"hell 1234567890 ab 23def" when using preg_replace('#\P{Nd}\P{Latin}#u', ' ', $str)

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're trying to do. Can you show us the correct output for your test case? Please edit your question and put it there, not in a comment.

Comment: Thank you Alan, I have updated my question and will provide further additions/questions within the body of the question instead of this comment field.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not set up to work with either PHP or Chinese, so I can't give you a definitive answer, but this should at least help you refine the question.  As I see it, it's basically a four-step process:

- get rid of undesirable characters like punctuation, replacing them with whitespace
- normalize whitespace: get rid of leading and trailing spaces, and collapse runs of two or more spaces to one space
- normalize case: replace any uppercase letters with their lowercase equivalents
- wherever a Chinese character is next to another non-whitespace character, separate the two characters with a space

For the first three steps, the first line of the code you posted should suffice:

```
$str = mb_strtolower(trim(preg_replace('#[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\.]+#u', ' ', $str)));
```

For the final step, I would suggest lookarounds:

```
$str = preg_replace(
    '#(?<=\S)(?=\p{Chinese})|(?<=\p{Chinese})(?=\S)#u',
    ' ', $str);
```

That should insert a space at any position where the next character is Chinese and the previous character is not whitespace, or the *previous* character is Chinese and the *next* character is not whitespace.

Comment: I tried using your lookaround method but when I tried it on my string (after replacing {Chinese} with the approrpiate {Han} Unicode Script) it ended up parsing out the string entirely.  I continued to experiment with Unicode scripts and ended up with something I was happy with which I posted below.  Thanks for all your help!